# haskell type signatur for returning type constructor

Tags: haskell, types, constructor, return-type

Is it possible to give a type signature for this `getConstructor` function?
The function works but i can't find out the way to write the return type.

```
module Main where

    data Letter a =
          A a
        | B a
        | C String
        deriving (Show)

    -- getConstructor :: String -> (a -> Letter ?) -- <== 
    getConstructor x
        | x == "a"  = A
        | x == "b"  = B
        | otherwise = C


    main = print $ theType
        where theType = (getConstructor "b") "its b!"
```

Main prints `B "its b!"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look:

```
getConstructor x
    | x == "a"  = A
    | x == "b"  = B
    | otherwise = C -- <= Let's inspect this line
```

That line returns `C :: String -> Letter a`. The previous line returns `B :: a -> Letter a`. These types must be equal, so `a ~ String`. Hence, the function becomes:

```
getConstructor :: String -> (String -> Letter String)
```

There is no way to dynamically choose the type at runtime with a function like this, since in Haskell, all types are known at compile-time. Hence, it's restricted to working on `String`s only.

Answer (score 2):

I simply entered your code into GHCi and asked it to tell me the type:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude|     data Letter a =
Prelude|           A a
Prelude|         | B a
Prelude|         | C String
Prelude|         deriving (Show)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> :{
Prelude|     getConstructor x
Prelude|         | x == "a"  = A
Prelude|         | x == "b"  = B
Prelude|         | otherwise = C
Prelude| :}
Prelude> :t getConstructor
getConstructor :: [Char] -> String -> Letter String
```

This makes sense, because it takes a `[Char]` (aka a `String` - that's the `x` argument) and returns one of `A`, `B` and `C`, which are the constructors for `Letter`. Being constructors they are also functions - in the case of `C` the type is clearly `String -> Letter a`, while `A` and `B` have type `a -> Letter a`. Since these are all possible return values of `getConstructor`, they must be the same type - the only way for that to happen is if `a` is always `String`. This gives us the type of `getConstructor` as `String -> (String -> Letter String)`, which is exactly what GHCi says above (with some minor rewriting).